# What do mkfs.xfs and modprobe do when mounting an Amazon EBS instance?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, modprobe

I'm looking through [this guide for how to add an EBS volume to an Amazon EC2 instance](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1663?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1), and I've found this little part of instructions hard to follow:

> Create an XFS file system on the EBS volume and mount it as /vol

```
grep -q xfs /proc/filesystems || sudo modprobe xfs
sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdh

echo "/dev/sdh /vol xfs noatime 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo mkdir -m 000 /vol
sudo mount /vol
```

> You now have a 10 GB (or whatever size you specified) EBS volume mounted under /vol with an XFS file system, and it will be automatically mounted if the instance reboots.

I don't believe I have `mkfs.xfs` installed, although `mkfs` is a valid command. This is a little too much piping and advanced syntax for me - I'm trying to figure out how to make this work on Ubuntu 10.04 and am not having any luck with it.

Can someone tell me what is being attempted here so I can try and understand it and get it working for my Ubuntu EC2 Instance?

**update**

A few things I figured out:

- on my instance I had to use `/dev/xvdh` and not `/dev/sdh`
- still not sure what `grep -q xfs /proc/filesystems || sudo modprobe xfs` is doing as running each of those commands does not show any results.
- afaik the fstab is just to automatically connect the volume at boot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep -q xfs /proc/filesystems || sudo modprobe xfs
```

`/proc/filesystems` lists all the filesystems that your kernel knows about.  (Try `cat /proc/filesystems` to see.  In the resulting list, `nodev` indicates that the filesystem does not expect an associated block device.)

So `grep -q xfs /proc/filesystems` is checking to see if your kernel knows about XFS.  (The `-q` means "don't print anything, just set the exit status.")  If not, it runs `sudo modprobe xfs` to load the XFS module.  (The `||` means "run the next command only if the previous command exited non-zero," and has nothing to do with a single `|` that creates a pipeline.)

```
sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdh
```

This creates an empty XFS filesystem on the block device `/dev/sdh` (i.e., it formats the partition).  You might have to install an XFS tools package (usually called `xfsprogs`) if you don't have `mkfs.xfs`.

```
echo "/dev/sdh /vol xfs noatime 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

This appends a line to `/etc/fstab` so the volume will be mounted automatically during boot.  The block device needs to match the one you formatted.

```
sudo mkdir -m 000 /vol
```

This creates the directory where the new volume will be mounted.  It could be anything you like.  It's created without access permissions (mode 000) so that nobody will write anything to the directory when the filesystem is not mounted.

```
sudo mount /vol
```

This mounts the volume immediately, so you don't have to reboot.  (It gets the mount parameters from `/etc/fstab`.)

Answer (score 2):

If `mkfs.xfs` is not installed, then you skipped this step in the article:

```
sudo apt-get install -y xfsprogs
```

You wrote:

> on my instance i had to use /dev/xvdh and not /dev/sdh

Yes, this is the way that attached volumes and ephemeral storage show up on modern versions of Ubuntu on EC2.  The article is a bit out of date with the name of the device, but I still do everything else as described in it.

Disclosure: I wrote [that article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1663).

Comment: Thanks Eric. Comments were closed and I was not having much luck figuring it out. I actually did not skip the first step, but turns out `/dev/sda1` was already full so it did not install with that command :) Mostly I was confused about there not being much explanation about that group of commands. Thanks for taking the time to write a great article - there is not too many good guides out there for ec2. Also, is `/proc/filesystems` still accurate? Or did that change to `/proc/fs` ?

Comment: @cwd, `/proc/filesystems` is a file that lists the known filesystems.  `/proc/fs` is a directory where certain filesystems provide more information about themselves and/or allow their parameters to be tweaked.